# PHP - Calculate days between two dates - not working in March and April 2013

Tags: php, date

I have problem with my PHP function. It was working until now, when I need to calculate number of days (or more precisely nights) between date 2013-03-28 and 2013-04-01. The result should be 4 (03/28 to 03/29, 03/29 to 03/30, 03/30 to 03/31 and 03/31 to 04/01) and my function returns 3. (When I use 2012-03-28 and 2012-04-01 instead of the same dates in 2013, it works correctly). Can you help me please?

```
function termLength($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
  $dateFrom = (($dateFrom instanceof DateTime) ? $dateFrom : new DateTime($dateFrom));
  $dateTo = (($dateTo instanceof DateTime) ? $dateTo : new DateTime($dateTo));

  $difference = $dateTo->format('U') - $dateFrom->format('U');
  return floor($difference / (60 * 60 * 24));
}

echo termLength('2013-03-28', '2013-04-01');

// output: 3
// it should be: 4
```

Can you help me, please? Thanks, J.

Comment: Well, it gives me 4 as answer.

Comment: Strange, I'm getting 3 too. Just replace your difference-calculation with the one provided by deceze (using DateInterval), and you should get the correct answer (worked for me).

Comment: Your problem is likely a timezone/DST problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$start = strtotime('2013-03-28');
$end = strtotime('2013-04-01');

$days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
```

Comment: It works, but ceil instead of floor? I think better will be round, and I don't know with this neither :-(... will it work in every case?

Comment: @user1817423 i think yes ,,, in ever case

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `DateTime` anyway, use the `DateInterval` mechanism:

```
$diff = $dateFrom->diff($dateTo);
echo $diff->format('%a');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to say, that I have PHP 5.2.9, so I can't use diff method of DateTime object, but thank you. BTW, it's true, this is working solution.

Comment: OK... Is there a DST change during that time in your timezone?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, I'm from the middle of the Europe - UTC/GMT +1 hour. But strtotime is working, so if the parameters will be instances of DateTime, I'll format it to 'Y-m-d' and after that I'll use strtotime (it seems to me a little bit stupid, but it's working :-) ).

Comment: Oh... mistake... I'm sorry, strtotime is not working the same way as DateTime->format('U'). What works is when I use round (or ceil) instead of floor, but will it work in the future, with every dates?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you convert it to timestamp, calculate the difference and then convert it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
round(($end_date - $start_date), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Function Body :**

```
function dateDifference($startDate = '', $endDate = '') {
  $startDateConverted = strtotime($startDate);
  $endDateConverted = strtotime($endDate);
  $substractedDate = $endDateConverted - $startDateConverted;
  $substractedDate = max(intval($substractedDate), 0);
  $dateDifference = round(abs($substractedDate) / 86400);
  return $dateDifference;
}
```

**Call :**

```
echo dateDifference('2013-03-28', '2013-04-01');
```

**Output :**

```
4
```